# play framework pretty print date

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

I've been googling for a while but I just can't seem to figure out how to pretty print a java date in a template

my `application.conf` contains

```
date.format="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
```

and this is what I'm trying in my template

```
${(event.date).format('dd MMMM yyyy')}
```

The event member looks like

```
@Required
public Date date;
```

Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using Play 1 formatting, which doesn't work in the Play 2 scala templates. You need to use the @ symbol in Play 2.

Try

```
 @event.date.format("dd MMMM yyyy")
```

Comment: You can also use i18n :   
1/define a key in conf/messages with "date={0, date}"   
2/ use @Messages.get("date", event.date)

Comment: @mba your solution is pretty cool, but how can we add the time (hour, minute, seconds) in the messages file ? Thanks

Comment: I can't try right now so maybe my response will be wrong but you can add a format :
date={0, date, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'}

Comment: To clarify, the solution by @mba is correct and would work.  Most users would want to remove the single quote character(').  The working solution is add a line in conf:messages such as:  date={0, date,MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss}