# Date formatting with locale in Play Framework 2.2

Tags: java, date, playframework, string-formatting, playframework-2.2

From what I can see in the auto-generated `application.conf` file, dates/times in Play Framework 2.2 are formatted according to the definition of `date.format` in that file. I have, for instance, defined

```
date.format=yyyy-MM-dd
date.format.dk=d. MMMM yyyy
```

These values, however, seem to be ignored by the framework when printing dates in Scala templates. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697184/play-framework-pretty-print-date) thread gives a solution where one enters the pattern directly into the template as `myDate.format("yyyy-MM-dd")`. (If using Jodatime I guess this becomes `myDate.toDate().format("yyyy-MM-dd")` since there is no `format()` defined on the `DateTime` class.) But not only does this force one to repeat the pattern each time a date is displayed, it also ignores the current locale.

So what is the intended way to format date and time in Play Framework 2.2.x with respect to different locales?

Comment: use joda-time  (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html)? They have a lot of nice built-in formatters.

Comment: I am already using Jodatime. The problem remains the same.

Comment: I am not sure if Play can accept whitespaces in the settings values. And in your case, I would have probably just make a method that takes the date and the locale and does what you want.

Comment: Still, I think and hope that there exists a "best practice" solution for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, if you want to hard code the locale *and* use JodaTime:

```
@(date: org.joda.DateTime)
@import java.util.Locale
@date.format("yyyy-MMM-dd", new Locale("sv", "SE"))
```

if you want to use the locale selected from the browser lang header (you will also need the request implicitly to your template):

```
@(date: org.joda.DateTime)(implicit lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)
@date.format("yyyy-MMM-dd", lang.toLocale)
```

I wrote a detailed blog entry about this (since I have seen the question so many times):

https://markatta.com/codemonkey/blog/2013/10/14/formatted-localized-dates-in-playframework-2/

Comment: What about using LocalDateTime in Java 8 instead of JodaTime? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found this here [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/FOZ26ADR84M) (I own no credit for this but I thought it could help somebody)

```
@(myDate: org.joda.time.DateTime)

@import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat

@defining(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")) { dateFormatter =>
    @dateFormatter.print(myDate) )
}
```

alternatively you can have this

```
val dateFormatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern(myDatePattern)
```

and call it in the template as (assuming it is stored in utils and Object Format):

```
@utils.Format.dateFormatter.print(myDate)
```

works very well for me