# Play Framework 2.2.3 : Define a default date format for data binding

Tags: java, date, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have searched for a while but I didn't find anything in the play documentation :

I have a class customer that contains a date :

```
private Date birthday;
```

My controller creates the object by binding the request params :

```
Form<Customer> userForm = form(Customer.class);
Customer customer = userForm.bindFromRequest().get();
```

At runtime, I get this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value
at play.libs.F$None.get(F.java:702) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at play.data.Form.get(Form.java:540) ~[play-java_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
```

I figured out that the problem comes from my date format that is submitted with this pattern : dd/MM/yyyy.

I was not able to find how to configure play to set this pattern for french users.
The only thing I found and that works is to use this annotation :

```
@Formats.DateTime(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date birthday;
```

I'm not satisfied because I don't want to put this annotation everywhere : the date format depends on the user local and should not be a const.

Moreover the play2 documentation does not explain what is the default pattern if nothing is specified...

I'd like to have a conf like that :

```
date.format.en = MM/dd/yyyy
date.format.fr = dd/MM/yyy
```

Do you know if it is possible with play2 ?

Any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335705/date-formatting-with-locale-in-play-framework-2-2), I think it will help you..

Comment: I already checked this link, it's a solution to format only a particular date in an html template file, and not to set a global configuration that works with databinding. But thank you :)